# iframe com designMode pegar html gerado dentro do iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Galera, estou usando um `iframe` junto com JavaScript para criar um editor de texto da forma citada abaixo:

```html
<iframe scrolling="auto" class="MINI_EDITOR" name="MINI_EDITOR">
```

E o código JavaScript é esse:

```js
function MINI_EDITOR_DE_TEXTO(){
    this.frameEdit = window.frames['MINI_EDITOR'].document;
    this.frameEdit.designMode = 'on';
}

function ADD_NEGRITO(){
    this.frameEdit.execCommand('bold', false, null);
}
```

Quando o usuário selecionar um texto e chamar a função `ADD_NEGRITO`, o texto muda para negrito e dentro do `iframe` é adicionada uma tag `<b>texto selecionado</b>`.

A minha pergunta é, eu preciso pegar todo o html que é gerado dentro do `iframe` e passar para uma variável. Tentei da seguinte forma, mas não deu certo:

```js
var IFRAME_PRICIPAL=document.querySelector(.MINI_EDITOR'').innerHTML;
alert(IFRAME_PRICIPAL);
```

Como posso fazer para que funcione? Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acessar o conteúdo do `iframe` dessa forma:

```js
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
```

e você consegue alterar o conteúdo assim:

```js
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>novo conteúdo</h1>";
```

O seu código então ficaria assim:

```js
var IFRAME_PRINCIPAL = document.querySelector('.MINI_EDITOR');
var conteudo = IFRAME_PRINCIPAL.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
alert(conteudo);
```